# How can I calculate the number of combinations of characters?

Tags: permutations, factorial, combinations

Given `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, how can I calculate the number of potential combinations from 1 to 5 long, without duplicating any character?  And always in alphabetical order.  Ultimately I need to calculate this for up to 10 strings of words (alpha, beta, gamma, etc.)

```
A
B
C
D
E
AB
AC
...
ABCDE
```

Answer (score 1):

For strings of length 1, that's P(5,1)

For strings of length 2, that's P(5,2)

...

For strings of length 5, that's P(5,5).

just add them all and you get the answer.

Comment: Thanks @aaa. I follow. Can you elaborate on how I calculate P(5,2)? I assume P(5,1) = 5 since it's just A, B, C, D, or E.  So is P(5,2) = 10? If so, that's 75 total combinations for (5*1)+(5*2)+(5*3)+(5*4)+(5*5). Does that sound right?

Comment: use the formula P(n,r) = n!/(n-r)!. So P(5,2) = 5!/3! = 5*4 = 20.

Comment: That's the permutation formula. See http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: Oops, that included P(5,0).  How about 5+20+60+120+120=325?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how this actually works.  If there's only 2 characters (A and B), then the expected outcome is: A, B, AB.  That's only 3 options.  I'd expect your Permutation Formula to give the same result: P(2,1) = 2!/(2-1)! = 2 ; P(2,2) = 2!/(2-2)! = 2.  2+2 = 4.  Why does the Permutation Formula return more than 3 results?  Is it counting for BA as well? How do I limit it to only alphabetical order?